# MTU does not tally with Ethertype for Ethernet II frame

Tags: ethernet, mtu

I just want to ask a quick , really confusing question. Online on Wikipedia, it states that the MTU for ethernet is 1500. Then as written on the same page, Ethernet Frame types: Ethernet II, it states on line 9 that "EtherType values must be greater than or equal to 1536 (0x0600). That value was chosen because the maximum length of the payload field of an Ethernet 802.3 frame is 1500 octets (0x05DC)". We clearly know that the MTU is 1500. In this case, 1536 bytes clearly contradicts the IEEE standard for MTU. what is going on here...???????

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Ethernet_II

Comment: Please check [this Q&A](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2962/how-was-the-mtu-size-for-ethernet-frames-calculated-as-1500-bytes?rq=1) let us know if you still have questions

Comment: I'm guessing that 1536 decimal does not equate to 1536 bytes

Comment: OK there's only 1 possible explanation left. The >= 1536 byte limit applies to the whole Ethernet II frame.

Comment: Either that or, my understanding from the article http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-isis-ext-eth-01, would be that Ethernet II payloads are not affected by the 1500 byte MTU limits. Or the MTU which is imposed upon Ethernet II is more than 1500 bytes.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the specs have not kept up with modern usage.  So, while the MTU for Ethernet II is officially 1500 (or 1518 thanks to dot1q specs), it's not unusual to use up to 9000 in certain situations (within managed networks.)  However, 802.3 frames are practically limited to 1500 (or perhaps 1536) bytes.

Comment: Plus, 0x600 is such a nice round number.  Once again, the answer might be, that was the number the committee members found least objectionable.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because that is what the spec requires - values between 1500 and 1536 are undefined and should not be used.

The relevant text of the 802.3-2012 spec is as follows:

> This two-octet field takes one of two meanings, depending on its
>   numeric value. For numerical evaluation, the first octet is the most
>   significant octet of this field.
>
> - a) If the value of this field is less than or equal to 1500 decimal    (05DC hexadecimal), then the Length/ Type field indicates the number of MAC client data octets contained in the subsequent MAC Client Data field of the basic frame (Length interpretation).
> - b) If the value of    this field is greater than or equal to 1536 decimal (0600    hexadecimal), then the Length/Type field indicates
>     the Ethertype of    the MAC client protocol (Type interpretation).
>
>   The Length and Type    interpretations of this field are mutually
>     exclusive.

There are historic (practical) reasons for making the lower bound on type to be substantially clear of the upper bound of length, given the vagaries of vendor implementations available at the time.